# Java, Android, Тайлы(Tiles), как поделить картинку?

Tags: tile, eclipse, android, java

Пните меня в нужном направлении, скиньте пример, пожалуйста. Как можно поделить картинку на секции(Тайлы или как их...), вот нужно:

Загрузить к примеру картинку:

www.google.com.ua/search?q=tile+sprite&tbm=isch&ei=29PTU5qUGYHNygOmzYLoCA#facrc=*&imgdii=*&imgrc=hoZwhakrNSdrDM%253A%3BCG54POPnrMU-cM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fread.pudn.com%252Fdownloads3%252Fsourcecode%252Fgames%252F6257%252Fisometric%252FChapter10%252FIsoHex10_3%252FIsoHex10_3__.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fgamedev.stackexchange.com%252Fquestions%252F33027%252Fopen-source-level-editor-for-html5-platform-game%3B529%3B397

Нужно, что-б ее поделило на куски, и можно было рисовать на канве эти куски, например: указали нарисовать кусок с индексом 1, он нарисовал, и так далее...

(Знаю, там фиг что понятно, просто мозги уже болят...)

Comment: посмотри тут https://github.com/ened/Android-Tiling-ScrollView
может найдешь ответ в коде

Comment: Вам известна ширина/высота тайла, и известен номер который нужно вырезать. Умножаете ширину на номер по вертикали и высоту на номер по горизонтали, теперь в находитесь в верхней левой точке тайла. Потом можно получить битмап исходной картинки и вырезать из него по известным координатам, нужный тайл. Естественно считать тайлы нужно от 0.

Answer (score 1):

[BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) позволяет декодировать только часть изображения. Можно после загрузки разрезать изображения и сохранить на диск, а потом уже отображать из кусков. Но минимальный API 10